# JavaScript / jquery Calculations issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i have issue with the below JavaScript code not taking current  GrossTotal() value until i rewrite Quantity or the UnitPrice values

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("[id*=gridpur]input[type=text][id*=txtCalc]").on('keyup', (function (e) {
     var unitprice = $(this).closest('tr').find("input[type=text][id*=txtCalcUnitprice]").val();
     var quantity = $(e.target).closest('tr').find("input[type=text][id*=txtCalcQuantity]").val();
     var total = unitprice * quantity;
     var cost = (total / GrossTotal())*100;
     $(e.target).closest('tr').find("[id*=lblTotal]").text(total);
     $(e.target).closest('tr').find("[id*=lblcost]").text(cost);
   }));
});

var gross;
function GrossTotal() {
  gross = 0;
  $("[id*=gridpur][id*=lblTotal]").each(function (index, item) {
    gross = gross + parseInt($(item).text());
  });
  $("[id*=lblGrandTotal]").text(gross);
  return gross;
}
```

for example if have entered the following values output i get which is not correct

```
ProductName UnitPrice Quantity  Amount  Cost %
product1     9         1          9     Infinity
product2     9         1          9     100
product3     9         1          9     50
```

I only get the correct values after rewriting Quantity or the UnitPrice which is

```
ProductName UnitPrice Quantity  Amount  Cost %
product1     9         1          9     33.3
product2     9         1          9     33.3
product3     9         1          9     33.3
```

Comment: You get `Infinity` when you divide by zero. The problem is that you fill in `lblTotal` after calling `GrossTotal()`, but `GrossTotal()` needs to use `lblTotal`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, you default them to 0 when you read the value from the input. Also Check for 0 before dividing it

```
unitprice = !isNaN(unitprice) ? 0 : unitprice;
quantity = !isNaN(quantity) ? 0 : quantity;

var total = unitprice * quantity;
var grossTotal = GrossTotal(),
    cost = 0;

if(grossTotal > 0) {
   cost = (total / grossTotal) *100;
}
```

Also it is a better habit to use radix when using `parseInt`

```
parseInt($(item).text(), 10)
```

Comment: thanks  but i am  still not getting current GrossTotal() value

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `GrossTotal()` adds up the values in all the `lblTotal` fields, but you're not filling them in until **after** you call it. Change these lines:

```
 var cost = (total / GrossTotal())*100;
 $(e.target).closest('tr').find("[id*=lblTotal]").text(total);
 $(e.target).closest('tr').find("[id*=lblcost]").text(cost);
```

to:

```
 $(e.target).closest('tr').find("[id*=lblTotal]").text(total);
 var cost = (total / GrossTotal())*100;
 $(e.target).closest('tr').find("[id*=lblcost]").text(cost);
```

Comment: No, it replaces those lines in the `keyup` handler.

Comment: It's hard for me to understand the question completely, because you don't show the HTML. So I don't know which fields are which. Can you make a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: i am using the code with asp grid view but i will try to make jsfiddle